# Kafka Consumer not showing from which partition its consuming

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using Kafka 0.10.2 single broker and zookeeper 3.4.9 single broker.I have three topics(t1,t2,t3) with 10 partition each .The messages that are there in t1 takes 20 sec to process. Messages that are there in t2 takes 10 min to process and t3 contains messages that take around 90 min to process. Now as I am running my consumers and adding extra consumers for parallelism for topic t1 is working fine. but for topic t2 and t3 after sometimes no consumer was showing attached to the partition .So I modified three consumer properties

```
"max.poll.records",10
"max.poll.interval.ms",36000000
"request.timeout.ms",36000000
```

after that, the consumers are working normally for all the topic. But as soon as I attach more consumers to topic t1,t2,t3 again they stop committing offset and get stuck in rebalancing. How can I solve this problem?

My Consumer Code:

```
class KafkaPollingConsumer implements Runnable {
private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaPollingConsumer.class)
    private static final String TAG = "[KafkaPollingConsumer]"
    private final KafkaConsumer<String, byte []> kafkaConsumer
    private Map<TopicPartition,OffsetAndMetadata> currentOffsetsMap = new HashMap<>()
    List topicNameList
    Map kafkaTopicConfigMap = new HashMap<String,Object>()
    Map kafkaTopicMessageListMap = new HashMap<String,List>()

    public KafkaPollingConsumer(String serverType, String groupName, String topicNameRegex){
        logger.debug("{} [Constructor] [Enter] Thread Name {} serverType group Name TopicNameRegex",TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName(),serverType,groupName,topicNameRegex)
        logger.debug("Populating Property for kafak consumer")
        Properties kafkaConsumerProperties = new Properties()
        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("group.id", groupName)
        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("key.deserializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer")
        kafkaConsumerProperties.put("value.deserializer", "com.custom.kafkaconsumer.deserializer.CustomObjectDeserializer")
        switch(serverType){
            case KafkaTopicConfigEntity.KAFKA_NODE_TYPE_ENUM.Priority.toString() :
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.priority.kafkaNode)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("enable.auto.commit",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.priority.consumer.enable.auto.commit)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.priority.consumer.auto.offset.reset)
                break
            case KafkaTopicConfigEntity.KAFKA_NODE_TYPE_ENUM.Bulk.toString() :
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("bootstrap.servers",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.bulk.kafkaNode)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("enable.auto.commit",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.bulk.consumer.enable.auto.commit)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("auto.offset.reset",ConfigLoader.conf.kafkaServer.bulk.consumer.auto.offset.reset)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("max.poll.records",10)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("max.poll.interval.ms",900000)
                kafkaConsumerProperties.put("request.timeout.ms",900000)
                break
            default :
                throw "Invalid server type"
                break
        }
        logger.debug("{} [Constructor] KafkaConsumer Property Populated {}",properties.toString())
        kafkaConsumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, byte []>(kafkaConsumerProperties)
        topicNameList = topicNameRegex.split(Pattern.quote('|'))
        logger.debug("{} [Constructor] Kafkatopic List {}",topicNameList.toString())
        logger.debug("{} [Constructor] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private class HandleRebalance implements ConsumerRebalanceListener {
        public void onPartitionsAssigned(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
        }

        public void onPartitionsRevoked(Collection<TopicPartition> partitions) {
            if(currentOffsetsMap != null && !currentOffsetsMap.isEmpty()) {
                logger.debug("{} In onPartitionsRevoked Rebalanced ",TAG)
                kafkaConsumer.commitSync(currentOffsetsMap)
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    void run() {
        logger.debug("{} Starting Thread ThreadName {}",TAG,Thread.currentThread().getName())
        populateKafkaConfigMap()
        initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap()
        String topicName
        String consumerClassName
        String consumerMethodName
        Boolean isBatchJob
        Integer batchSize = 0
        final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread()
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                logger.error("{},gracefully shutdowning thread {}",TAG,mainThread.getName())
                kafkaConsumer.wakeup()
                try {
                    mainThread.join()
                } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
                    logger.error("{} Error : {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
                }
            }
        })
        kafkaConsumer.subscribe(topicNameList , new HandleRebalance())
        try{
            while(true){
                logger.debug("{} Starting Consumer with polling time in ms 100",TAG)
                ConsumerRecords kafkaRecords = kafkaConsumer.poll(100)
                for(ConsumerRecord record: kafkaRecords){
                    topicName = record.topic()
                    DBObject kafkaTopicConfigDBObject = kafkaTopicConfigMap.get(topicName)
                    consumerClassName = kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.CLASS_NAME_KEY)
                    consumerMethodName = kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.METHOD_NAME_KEY)
                    isBatchJob = kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.IS_BATCH_JOB_KEY)
                    logger.debug("Details about Message")
                    logger.debug("Thread {}",mainThread.getName())
                    logger.debug("Topic {}",topicName)
                    logger.debug("Partition {}",record.partition().toString())
                    logger.debug("Offset {}",record.offset().toString())
                    logger.debug("clasName {}",consumerClassName)
                    logger.debug("methodName {}",consumerMethodName)
                    logger.debug("isBatchJob {}",isBatchJob.toString())
                    if(isBatchJob == true){
                        batchSize = Integer.parseInt(kafkaTopicConfigDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.BATCH_SIZE_KEY).toString())
                        logger.debug("batchSize {}",batchSize.toString())
                    }
                    Object message = record.value()
                    logger.debug("message {}",message.toString())
                    publishMessageToConsumers(consumerClassName,consumerMethodName,isBatchJob,batchSize,message,topicName)
                    Thread.sleep(60000)
                    currentOffsetsMap.put(new TopicPartition(record.topic(), record.partition()),new OffsetAndMetadata(record.offset() +1))
                }
                logger.debug("{} Commiting Messages to Kafka",TAG)
                kafkaConsumer.commitSync(currentOffsetsMap)
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptException exception){
            logger.error("{} In InterruptException",TAG)
            logger.error("{} Exception {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
        }
        catch (WakeupException exception) {
            logger.error("{} In WakeUp Exception",TAG)
            logger.error("{} Exception {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
        }
        catch(Exception exception){
            logger.error("{} In Exception",TAG)
            logger.error("{} Exception {}",TAG,exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
        }
        finally {
            logger.error("{} In finally commiting remaining offset ",TAG)
            publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages()
            kafkaConsumer.commitSync(currentOffsetsMap)
            kafkaConsumer.close()
            logger.error("{} Exiting Consumer",TAG)
        }
    }

    private void publishMessageToConsumers(String consumerClassName,String consumerMethodName,Boolean isBatchJob,Integer batchSize,Object message, String topicName){
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToConsumer] Enter",TAG)
        if(isBatchJob == true){
            publishMessageToBatchConsumer(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName,batchSize, message, topicName)
        }
        else{
            publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName, message)
        }
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToConsumer] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer(String consumerClassName, String consumerMethodName, message){
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer] Enter",TAG)
        executeConsumerMethod(consumerClassName,consumerMethodName,message)
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToNonBatchConsumer] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void publishMessageToBatchConsumer(String consumerClassName, String consumerMethodName, Integer batchSize, Object message, String topicName){
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToBatchConsumer] Enter",TAG)
        List consumerMessageList = kafkaTopicMessageListMap.get(topicName)
        consumerMessageList.add(message)
        if(consumerMessageList.size() == batchSize){
            logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToBatchConsumer] Pushing Messages In Batches",TAG)
            executeConsumerMethod(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName, consumerMessageList)
            consumerMessageList.clear()
        }
        kafkaTopicMessageListMap.put(topicName,consumerMessageList)
        logger.debug("{} [publishMessageToBatchConsumer] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void populateKafkaConfigMap(){
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] Enter",TAG)
        KafkaTopicConfigDBService kafkaTopicConfigDBService = KafkaTopicConfigDBService.getInstance()
        topicNameList.each { topicName ->
            DBObject kafkaTopicDBObject = kafkaTopicConfigDBService.findByTopicName(topicName)
            kafkaTopicConfigMap.put(topicName,kafkaTopicDBObject)
        }
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] kafkaConfigMap {}",TAG,kafkaTopicConfigMap.toString())
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap(){
        logger.debug("{} [initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap] Enter",TAG)
        topicNameList.each { topicName ->
            kafkaTopicMessageListMap.put(topicName,[])
        }
        logger.debug("{} [populateKafkaConfigMap] kafkaTopicMessageListMap {}",TAG,kafkaTopicMessageListMap.toString())
        logger.debug("{} [initializeKafkaTopicMessageListMap] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void executeConsumerMethod(String className, String methodName, def messages){
        try{
            logger.debug("{} [executeConsumerMethod] Enter",TAG)
            logger.debug("{} [executeConsumerMethod] className  {} methodName {} messages {}",TAG,className,methodName,messages.toString())
            Class.forName(className)."$methodName"(messages)
        } catch (Exception exception){
            logger.error("{} [{}] Error while executing method : {} of class: {} with params : {} - {}", TAG, Thread.currentThread().getName(), methodName,
                    className, messages.toString(), exception.getStackTrace().join("\n"))
        }
        logger.debug("{} [executeConsumerMethod] Exit",TAG)
    }

    private void publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages(){
        logger.debug("{} [publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages] Enter",TAG)
        String consumerClassName = null
        String consumerMethodName = null
        kafkaTopicMessageListMap.each { topicName,messageList ->
            DBObject kafkaTopicDBObject = kafkaTopicConfigMap.get(topicName)
            consumerClassName = kafkaTopicDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.CLASS_NAME_KEY)
            consumerMethodName = kafkaTopicDBObject.get(KafkaTopicConfigEntity.METHOD_NAME_KEY)
            logger.debug("{} Pushing message in topic {} className {} methodName {} ",TAG,topicName,consumerClassName,consumerMethodName)
            if(messageList != null && messageList.size() > 0){
                executeConsumerMethod(consumerClassName, consumerMethodName, messageList)
                messageList.clear()
                kafkaTopicMessageListMap.put(topicName,messageList)
            }
        }
        logger.debug("{} [publishAllKafkaTopicBatchMessages] Exit",TAG)
    }
```

Consumer Properties are :

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000 auto.offset.reset = earliest bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092] check.crcs = true client.id = consumer-1 connections.max.idle.ms = 540000 enable.auto.commit = false exclude.internal.topics = true fetch.max.bytes = 52428800 fetch.max.wait.ms = 500 fetch.min.bytes = 1 group.id = t1 heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000 interceptor.classes = null key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576 max.poll.interval.ms = 36000000 max.poll.records = 10 metadata.max.age.ms = 300000 metric.reporters = [] metrics.num.samples = 2 metrics.recording.level = INFO metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000 partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor] receive.buffer.bytes = 65536 reconnect.backoff.ms = 50 request.timeout.ms = 36000000 retry.backoff.ms = 100 sasl.jaas.config
= null sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000 sasl.kerberos.service.name = null sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter =
0.05 sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8 sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI security.protocol = PLAINTEXT send.buffer.bytes = 131072 session.timeout.ms = 10000 ssl.cipher.suites = null ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1] ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null ssl.key.password = null ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509 ssl.keystore.location = null ssl.keystore.password = null ssl.keystore.type = JKS ssl.protocol = TLS ssl.provider = null ssl.secure.random.implementation = null ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX ssl.truststore.location = null ssl.truststore.password = null ssl.truststore.type = JKS value.deserializer = class com.custom.kafkaconsumer.deserializer.CustomObjectDeserializer
```

Note group.id are diffferent for all 3 (t1,t2,t3)

Consumer State :

```
TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                       HOST                           CLIENT-ID
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-1-393fe17d-514e-49b7-a421-ce449af73d14   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-1-7b9a53a3-4c82-4e79-9a63-36566ae3f71f   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-1
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-2-997eb524-71d4-48da-813f-178e95c01edb   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
-                              -          -               -               -          consumer-2-8fb34ec9-338c-4f53-91ca-fb4d24586a4c   /127.0.0.1                     consumer-2
t2        8          3219            3515            296        -                                                 -                              -
t2        1          3904            4202            298        -                                                 -                              -
t2        6          3207            3490            283        -                                                 -                              -
t2        0          38661           39055           394        -                                                 -                              -
t2        5          3181            3485            304        -                                                 -                              -
t2        7          3285            3581            296        -                                                 -                              -
t2        4          3914            4223            309        -                                                 -                              -
t2        3          3719            4022            303        -                                                 -                              -
t2        2          3882            4202            320        -                                                 -                              -
t2        9          3354            3626            272        -                                                 -
```